# Difference between internet and intranet applications in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have doubt about the Internet and intranet applications.

I saw some explanation about it.

They explenations are like :

> **Internet** Application like a Web application with using form authentication
>
> **Intranet** Application like a Window application with using windows authentication

So my **Question No 1 :**

Please explain the more details about the different between Internet and intranet application.

**No 2 :**

We can use windows base aouthentication in Internet project by using ***Active directory***, etc.But  *is any possible way to use web based( form ) authentication in Intranet (windows application) project?*

***Important***   : This ***SO*** have not duplication of question by the title name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use any authentication method you like. The templates provided are just that: templates. Nobody forces you to use it as provided.
Using Windows authentication in an Intranet application just makes sense, since you don't want to constantly log in to applications in a corporate environment.

If you don't need authentication, then you can also skip authentication and authorization completly.

The main difference between an Intranet application and an Internet application if you will, is that one is public facing and the other is only available to a confined audience.